# Visual Studio 13, "edit hotkey"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Not really sure what to put as title, so feel free to suggest edits.

Anyway I was just wondering if there's a hotkey in Visual Studio 13 to "edit/change" what I just wrote. Here's an example I have that will probably clear it up:

Let's say I want to write `DateTime.now` but I accidently autocomplete it to `DateTime.UtcNow` is there a hotkey I can press that will bring up Intellisense and allow me to rewrite/edit the last part?

Comment: Ctrl+Z - Undo. Then Ctrl + Space to open Intellisense again.

Comment: That'll undo to before I hit autocomplete, which would work but not really what I want. What I want is something that'll delete everything after '.' and bring up intellisense autocomplete at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+Z and than again Ctrl+Space.

So you can create a macro for your own use that combines the commands:

- Edit.Undo
- Edit.CompleteWord

Edit: I just see that you asked for VS-2013, this version does not support macros any longer. So the only way to perform this action with one keystroke is to create an addin.